# iPhone MoviePlayer example, where did the button and label come from

Tags: iphone, video

I had working with the iPhone example named "MoviePlayer" where it show you how to add an overlay over a MPMoviePlayer.

This works great, but I can't find where did they set the button and label? how can I add some controls of my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked too soon.

Yet, if someone needs it: 
1. open the MainWindow.xib with Interface builder (double-click should work) 
2. in the xib window, there is a view named "My overlay view".

this is it.